# Is it acceptable to ask those having criticism and feedback to put some effort towards providing it?

Tags: colleagues

I support a small web application at work in my companies equivalent of "20%" time

Now, as with anything, people have feedback, suggestions, criticisms,etc about it.

Since I personally find it impractical to keep track of feedback randomly, I ask them to write a mail to the feedback mail present on the site, use the prominent feedback box, or to send it to me personally as a mail.

This has a side effect of having people frame out their issues better and makes it clearer to understand pain points than random discussions

The problem is that hardly anyone sends the written feedback, yet many people crib about things.

Am I doing something different\wrong by asking people to make the effort of sending their feedback to me through a written channel?

Comment: No, you're basically creating a bug database, which is a good thing.  The key to getting people to use it is to stop responding to requests (you can still point them to where they should send feedback, etc to) that don't follow the proper channels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I doing something different\wrong by asking people to make the effort of sending their feedback to me through a written channel?

People like to complain about anything and everything.

Especially if someone does something which makes them look bad/lazy or otherwise hurts their image. At a certain point anyone doing good work will feel this way, because generally speaking people like to complain and criticize  (it's also considerably easier to tear someone else down than it is to create the similar quality work).

Try phrasing things like, "I appreciate the feedback but it would be a lot easier to work to include those suggestions if I have them documented - can you give me an email through the site so I can track your thoughts?"

> This has a side effect of having people frame out their issues better and makes it clearer to understand pain points than random discussions

This is a good thing. Also keep in mind if it's a significant enough pain point to cause problems it's worth a few minutes to create a request.

If it's not? Then it's probably not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 5):

As with so much in life, it depends.

First, you say that you are working on this as part of your "20% time" which implies that it is a site that you are choosing to champion and that you may be trying to build up support for.  If that is the case, it makes sense to be a bit more open about taking feedback in whatever form you can get it.  If you are trying to convince people to use the site rather than following a "business as usual" process, that implies that the users have a choice about whether to use your system or not.  That means that the users will often be much less invested in the site than you are and will generally be much less likely to go through a lot of effort to improve it.  A lot of the feedback is going to be explanations of why someone isn't using the site because it doesn't do something that they need.  Just like you don't go around sending feedback to companies whose products you choose not to buy, they may not feel that it's worth their time to do more than mention something in passing.  If this is a site that the organization mandates that everyone use, there is generally much more incentive to provide feedback so that requests can be prioritized.

Second, who is providing the feedback?  Some user bases are going to require some developer interaction in order to provide meaningful feedback because they are not particularly technically savvy.  If the site gives pick lists to warehouse workers that are filling orders, for example, it's likely that you'll have much better feedback if you have a conversation about the problem they're having rather than asking them to send an email both because it allows you to understand the underlying problem rather than just the suggested fix and because it lets you ask follow-up questions.  Other user bases are going to require some developer interaction because they're busy.  If the site is presenting a bunch of dashboards to senior management, they might mention something to you but that might not be important enough for them to sit down and write an email to explain.  These requests also tend to be sufficiently complex that you need to have a conversation (or several) in order to understand all the implicit assumptions and implied requirements.

Third, is it really easier for the users to send you an email than it is for you to write down the request after a quick chat?  There are certainly cases where it is-- I have no problem asking fellow developers to send me an email when they find an issue with something I've written because I know they'll provide enough information for me to resolve the issue without a lot of followup.  If many business users tried that, though, I'd more frequently get something that lacked some important information and context (they're not developers, after all) and I'd have to go through multiple rounds of followup to gather the requirements before putting together the summary email at the end anyway to capture the requirements so that I could log the bug.  In that case, it's often easier to just gather the requirements verbally and send the email than to make them put their thoughts into words.

Answer (score 2):

> Since I personally find it impractical to keep track of feedback
>   randomly,

If this feedback is coming from superiors, you better figure-out how to document it, because they're not going to do it for you at your request. I typically ask people to send an email because I think their idea is important and I don't want to forget. For users that don't find your website to be critical for them, they're not going to bother.

> This has a side effect of having people frame out their issues better
>   and makes it clearer to understand pain points than random discussions

Don't be too sure about this. If reluctant users are forced to do this, you're going to get very short responses. Too many people Tweet and text and don't go into detail This is a problem in technical areas. You may find yourself spending more time with email replies asking for clarification and may be better off just picking up the phone.

If people insist on verbal suggestions, ask to schedule a meeting so you can go over it or send you an email. Is it too much to ask for you to meet with people who are trying to improve your website and take a few notes? I believe they call this the shoe being on the other foot.

Answer (score 2):

I call this the "Rush Limbaugh Anti-Pattern."  It's a lot easier to complain vocally than it is to do something that's actually productive.  (For our Non-U.S. members, Rush Limbaugh is a quasi-political commentator who is (in)famous for ranting about problems with our government, particularly the Democratic party, while offering no constructive ideas or solutions to those problems.)

Users who cannot be bothered to document their problem or request are just ranting, and while they can be destructive and divisive, are not helpful.  You have to find ways to identify them and either bring them into the fold or to effectively silence them.

Justin Cave's suggestion about scheduling meetings is a good one, but you must go one step further:  Schedule a meeting with the complainer and their supervisor / manager.  Put in the meeting request a prerequisite (Every meeting request should have agenda and prerequisites, but that's another subject) that the complainer is to provide the outline of the issue and a presentation on how it should be different, the business case for the change, and the impact the change would have to their operations.  If it is a small issue, a 15-minute meeting is fine.

After 2 or 3 of these meetings, one one of three things will happen:

1. The supervisor/manager will see that this person is just ranting, and will tell him to quit wasting everyone's time.
2. The supervisor/manager will realize that the person would save everyone a lot of time if they would just use the feedback system.
3. You will develop engagement with the user base, as they see a system in place to approach you and you will get users putting effort into structuring their requests.

This may seem a little passive-aggressive (and some would say actually is), but the chronic complainers can torpedo a project, and have to be managed like any other project risk.